# Create Custom Component Model (TimerPanel)

Tags: model, wicket, custom-component

this question is about **good Wicket Design**. We have several ways how we could implement it, but want to get some ideas how to design it better. We just want to build a simple *TimerPanel*, with a label and a Timer (some kind of StopWatch).

How should we design its *Model*. For sure we need the `IModel<LocalDateTime> timerUntil`. But how can we define the text of the *Label* in the *TimerPanel*?

The *TimerPanel* will be used in a *ParentPanel*. The ParentPanel has a model like this:

```
public class ParentDto {
  private LocalDateTime timerAValidUntil;
  private LocalDateTime timerBValidUntil;
}
```

Since the *ParentDto* does not have any information about the label of the TimerPanel, the following

```
new PropertyModel(getDefaultModel(), "timerAValidUntil")
```

is not enough.

**Here the the Question**: Should we define a fixed wicketId, lets say `timerLabel` for the Label in the `TimerPanel`, and the Parent Panel has to define it in its `Panel.properties.xml`?. Like **(Option A)**

```
timerPanelA:timerLabel
```

or is ist better to create a new ModelObject, like **(Option B)**

```
public class TimerDto() {
   String timerLabel;
   IModel<LocalDateTime> timerValidUntil;
}
```

We always try to connect our models, so if we change the ModelObject in one Panel it is also changed in all dependant Panels. **Please share your knowledge... Thx**.

Answer (score 1):

The usage of resource keys in ParentPanel (option A) is perfectly fine, this even allows you to i18n the labels.
If your timer entity does not have a label (e.g. edited by the user), I don't see any gain in adding one.

Wicket can work with almost any objects inside models, so there's no need to build an intermediate layer of DTOs. You will be developing much faster by binding your components directly to your actual entities.

I'd might be mistaken but the *Dto suffix from your example gives me the impression, that you're going the opposite direction.

Answer (score 1):

Option A would be better, and you could use a StringResourceModel, to display both the label and the time in one control.

```
PropertyModel timerModel = new PropertyModel(getDefaultModel(), "timerAValidUntil");
StringResourceModel labelModel = new StringResourceModel("timerLabel", this, timerModel));
Label timerLabel = new Label("timerLabel", labelModel);
```

If you want it to have a 'stop timer' action, you can add a link inside the label. See 'Putting wicket components into the message' in [Everything about Wicket internationalization](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Everything+about+Wicket+internationalization)